# Variant of Cauchy Functional Equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Consider the equation $$f(kx-f(x))=x=kf(x)-f(f(x))$$ for montonic $f$.

What can we say about the solutions to this equation. Comparing with Cauchy equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, I think the solution must be somewhat close to being linear. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The $ = x = $ in between, is that meant to be there?

Comment: @RutgerMoody yes, that is meant to be there. I think that makes the function bijective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(kx-f(x))=x \tag{1} $
$kf(x)-f(f(x)) =x \tag{2}$

> From $(1) \implies $ $f(x) $ is surjective.

$(2) \implies $ Let $f(a)=f(b)\implies a=kf(a)-f(f(a))=kf(b)-f(f(b)) = b \implies $

> $f(x)$ is injective.

This means $f(x)$ is **bijective**. So $f^{-1}(x)$ exists.

$(1)\implies f(kf^{-1}(x)-f(f^{-1}(x)))=f^{-1}(x) \implies f^{-1}(f(kf^{-1}(x)-x))=f^{-1}(f^{-1}(x)) \implies  x =kf^{-1}(x) -f^{-1}(f^{-1}(x))   $
$(2) \implies  kx-f^{-1}(x) = f(x) \implies f^{-1}( kx-f^{-1}(x)) = x   $ $\implies$

> If $f(x)$ is a solution to $(1)$ and $(2)$ then so is $f^{-1}(x)=kx-f(x)$

Let : $ g(x)=-f(-x) $.
$(1)\implies -f(-kx-f(-x))=x \implies g(kx+f(-x))=x \implies  g(kx-g(x))=x  $
$(2)\implies -kf(-x)+f(f(-x)) =x \implies kg(x)+f(-g(x))=x\implies  kg(x)-g(g(x))=x $

> $\implies $  If $f(x)$ is a solution to $(1)$ and $(2)$ then so is $  g(x):=-f(-x)$.

Fixed points :
From $ (2) $ we see that if there exists an $ a $ for which $f(a)=a $ then: $ kf(a)-f(f(a)) =a \implies ka  =2a \implies a=0 \lor k=2 $ 
$f(ka-f(a))=a \implies ka-f(a) =a \implies  ka  =2a \implies a=0 \lor k=2 $
Also we see that if there exists an $ a $ for which $f(a)=-a  $ then: $ kf(a)-f(f(a)) =a \implies -ka  =2a \implies a=0 \lor k=-2 $ 
$f(ka-f(a))=a \implies -ka-a  =a \implies  -ka  =2a \implies a=0 \lor k=-2 $

> From the above we see that when $k=2$ , then $f(x)=x$ is a solution. And when $k=-2$ , then $f(x)=-x$  is a solution.

**General solution :**

*(Note: I screwed up a couple of times before here. Apologies to everyone who read it, if anyone did..I do think this must be the correct argument.)*
We transform $f(x)$ into a new function $g(x)$ like this : $g(x)+\frac{kx}{2}=f(x)$ 
Which gives : 
$ g(\frac{kx}{2}-g(x))-\frac{kg(x)}{2} =(1-\frac{k^2}{4})x \tag{1a}$
$-g(\frac{kx}{2}+g(x))+\frac{kg(x)}{2} =(1-\frac{k^2}{4})x \tag{2a}$
There are two cases to consider :

**Case 1 when $k^2 \neq 4 $ :** 
Let $g(a)=0 \implies (1a) \implies  g(\frac{ka}{2})  =(1-\frac{k^2}{4})a $
$(2a) \implies  -g(\frac{ka}{2} )  =(1-\frac{k^2}{4})a $

> $ \implies a=0  \implies g(0)=f(0)=0 \enspace (  k^2 \neq 4 ) $

From bijectivity and monotonicity I think we can conclude that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be continuous, (and maybe even differentiable).
Here I'll assume $g(x)$ can be written as a Taylor series around $x=0$ :
We calculate the first and second derivative :

$ g'(\frac{kx}{2}-g(x))(\frac{k}{2}-g'(x))-\frac{kg'(x)}{2} =(1-\frac{k^2}{4}) $
$-g'(\frac{kx}{2}+g(x))(\frac{k}{2}+g'(x))+\frac{kg'(x)}{2} =(1-\frac{k^2}{4}) $

$ g'(0)(\frac{k}{2}-g'(0))-\frac{kg'(0)}{2} =(1-\frac{k^2}{4}) $
$-g'(0)(\frac{k}{2}+g'(0))+\frac{kg'(0)}{2} =(1-\frac{k^2}{4}) $

> $ g'(0) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} $

$ g''(\frac{kx}{2}-g(x))(\frac{k}{2}-g'(x))^2+g'(\frac{kx}{2}-g(x))(-g''(x))-\frac{kg''(x)}{2} =0 $
$-g''(\frac{kx}{2}+g(x))(\frac{k}{2}+g'(x))^2 -g'(\frac{kx}{2}+g(x))(g''(x))+\frac{kg''(x)}{2} =0 $
$ g''(0)(\frac{k}{2}-g'(0))^2+g'(0)(-g''(0))-\frac{kg''(0)}{2} =0 $
$-g''(0)(\frac{k}{2}+g'(0))^2 -g'(0)(g''(0))+\frac{kg''(0)}{2} =0 $
$ g'(0)g''(0)( k + 1) =0 \implies  g''(0)=0 \enspace \lor \enspace k=-1 $
 
$-g''(0)(\frac{k^2}{4}+(k+1)g'(0)+g'(0)^2 -\frac{k}{2})  =0 \implies \text{(with $k=-1$ and $g'(0)^2=\frac{k^2}{4}-1$ )} \implies -g''(0)(\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{4}-1 -\frac{1}{2})  =0 \implies g''(0)=0  $

> $\implies g''(0) =0 $ . Also the higher derivatives in $x=0$ are $0$ (I think).

> So for $k^2 \neq 4 $ we have : $g(x)=\pm \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} \cdot x$. Or : $f(x)=( \frac{k}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} ) \cdot x  $

Fill this in in the original equations to check :

$g(x)= \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} \cdot x$
$ \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} (\frac{k}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1}  )x-\frac{k}{2}\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1}   x  =(1-\frac{k^2}{4})x $
$-\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} (\frac{k}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} )x+\frac{k}{2}\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1}   x  =(1-\frac{k^2}{4})x $

$g(x)= -\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} \cdot x$
$ -\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1}(\frac{k}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} )x+\frac{k}{2}\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1}  x =(1-\frac{k^2}{4})x $
$+\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} (\frac{k}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} )x-\frac{k}{2}\sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1}   x  =(1-\frac{k^2}{4})x $
$\square$

**Case 2 when $k^2 = 4 $ :**

$ g(\frac{kx}{2}-g(x))-\frac{kg(x)}{2} =0 \tag{1b}$
$-g(\frac{kx}{2}+g(x))+\frac{kg(x)}{2} =0 \tag{2b}$

We see that $g(x)$ must be constant ([see here for example : Functions $f$ satisfying $ f\circ f(x)=2f(x)-x,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/327848)) and fill in as a general solution :

> For $k  = 2 $ we have : $g(x)= c $. Or : $f(x)= c + x $.

> For $k  = -2 $ we have : $g(x)= 0 $. Or : $f(x)= - x $.

$\square$

**Below some solutions to modified versions :**


 
Below some things that can be proved about the more general version of $(1)$ and $(2)$ : equation $(3)$ :
**More general case without '$=x=$' in between :**

$$
f(kx-f(x))=kf(x)-f(f(x)) \tag{3}
$$

> $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=kx$ and $f(x)=\frac{kx}{2}$ are all solutions to $(3)$ .

$f(x)=0$ is trivial.
 
Let: $f(x)=kx \implies \\ f(kx-f(x))=kf(x)-f(f(x)) \implies f(kx-kx)=k^2x-f(kx) \implies 0=0 $

Let: $f(x)=\frac{kx}{2} \implies f(kx-\frac{kx}{2})=k\frac{kx}{2}-f(\frac{kx}{2}) \implies \frac{k^2x}{2}= \frac{k^2x}{2}  \enspace  \square $

There are many more solutions, including the ones above for $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Below a solution to a modified version of $(1)$ and $(2)$ : equation $(4)$ and $(5)$:
**Modified case with '$=\frac{k^2x}{4}=$' in between :**

$f(kx-f(x))=\frac{k^2x}{4} \tag{4} $
$kf(x)-f(f(x)) =\frac{k^2x}{4}  \tag{5}$

> $f(x)=\frac{kx}{2}$ is a solution to $(4)$ and $(5)$.

Let: $f(x)=\frac{kx}{2} \implies f(kx-\frac{kx}{2})=\frac{k^2x}{4} \implies  \frac{k^2x}{4}=\frac{k^2x}{4} $ and : 
$ k\frac{kx}{2}-f(\frac{kx}{2}) =\frac{k^2x}{4} \implies \frac{k^2x}{2}- \frac{k^2x}{4}  =\frac{k^2x}{4}  $
$ \enspace  \square $

Comment: great answer, the answer would be complete if you provide proofs for expanding into taylor series

Comment: @vidyarthi Thanks! I realize this was an assumption, it might be that this can be proved. But then again it might be that there are other exotic functions (eg fractal-like) so weird in their definition that they are non-differentiable solutions to the above. Allways hard to prove a negative. I'll get back to it if I can find an answer.