# If$f^{-1}(x)=kx-f(x)$, then what can we say about $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If $f^{-1}(x)=kx-f(x)\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ for a strictly increasing $f$ and $k$ a constant, then what can be said about $f$?

I think the answer is of the form $f(x)=x+c$, for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Any hints. Thanks beforehand

Comment: Since you define $f^{-1}$ and $f$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, are you assuming that $f is also unbounded?

Comment: Does the definition mean $D_f=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @MyGlasses yes the domain the set of real numbers.

Comment: At least some solutions can be found here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122305/variant-of-cauchy-functional-equation/2132515#2132515

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** $f$ is convex iff $f^{-1}$ is concave.

${\bf Proof.}$ Let $x_1, x_2\in D_f$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ so with $g=f^{-1}$
\begin{eqnarray}
g(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)&=&k(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)-f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\\
&\geq&
k\lambda x_1+k(1-\lambda)x_2-\lambda f(x_1)-(1-\lambda)f(x_2)\\
&=&
\lambda g(x_1)+(1-\lambda)g(x_2)
\end{eqnarray}

**(2)** If $k<0$ then $g=f^{-1}$ is decreasing.

${\bf Proof.}$ Let $x_1, x_2\in D_f$ and $x_1<x_2$ then $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ and  $kx_1>kx_2$ hence $g(x_1)>g(x_2)$.

**(3)** If $k\neq 2$ then $f(x)\neq x+c$ for a $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

${\bf Proof.}$ If $f(x)=x+c$ then $f^{-1}(x)=x-c$ and $x-c=kx-x-c$ therefore $k=2$.

**(4)** If $f(x)$ be continuous, then 
$$\int f^{-1}(x)dx=\frac12kx^2-\int f(x)dx+C$$
integration by parts shows $\int f^{-1}(x)dx=xf(x)-\int f(x)dx$ thus
$$f(x)=\frac12kx+\frac{C}{x}$$

Comment: how can we prove that?

Comment: how can you say that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: still, how can you prove that?

Comment: If $k = 0$, $x = f^{-1}(f(x)) = -f(f(x))$.
Can that have a real solution? I can't think of any way it could, especially given the stipulation that $f$ is strictly increasing. Does that mean $k \not=0$?

Comment: thanks for your reply, by the way is the converse of $(3)$ in your answer valid?

Comment: I don't understand how you came to conclusion (4). Here a conflicting result: For $k^2 \neq 4 $ we have :  $f(x)= (\frac{k}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} )\cdot x  $
$\implies f^{-1}(x)= \frac{x}{( \frac{k}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} )}$
$\implies f^{-1}(x)+f(x)= \frac{x}{( \frac{k}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} )}+(\frac{k}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} )\cdot x$

$\implies f^{-1}(x)+f(x)= \frac{( \frac{k}{2}   \pm \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1}   )}{( \frac{k}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} )}\cdot kx$

Comment: What I meant was: $(\frac{k}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{4}-1} ) \neq \frac{k}{2}$

Comment: @RutgerMoody Maybe you right, I think (4) is wrong.