# property of functions satisfying $f(x-f(x))=f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

Assume $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x-f(x))=f(x)$ and:

1) has the intermediate value property

or

2) is continuous.

Does $f$ have to be constant?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is bijective, then $f(x)=c$ is the only possible case.

Comment: "If $f(x)$ is bijective then $f(x) = c$" But $f(x) = c$ is not bijective so I guess what you are saying is that there cannot be any bijective solution?

Comment: @Winther :O  Wow, I guess I'm smarter than I thought

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/327848/147873) which works with the same functional equation.