Function that satisfies $f(x-f(x))=f(x)$
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function satisfying
$$
f(x - f(x)) = f(x), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Claim: The only solution is $f(x) = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
By setting $y = x - f(x)$, we derive $f(x - 2f(x)) = f(x)$, and by induction,
$$
f(x - nf(x)) = f(x), \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
How can we proceed to prove the claim?

@AntonyTheo. This $f$ cannot be one-to-one.

Somebody shared a link to this answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/327848/620957), which I still think is relevant even though it doesn't fully answer this question. The function corresponds to $g$ in that answer, although $g(x)+x$ is already known to be increasing in that answer. But it may still help to have the link

Can you show that $f(x)$ must have an horizontal Asymptote, that is the same at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$? If you can, then can you use the uniqueness of the limit and the fact $f(x-nf(x))=f(x)$ to conclude something.

@Milten I'll just note that if we had uniform continuity then the answer you linked can still be used to show that we'd have a constant, in case it could help. I haven't seen many functional equations where that's a part of the path to the solution but who knows.

This solution is due to a colleague o'mine.
Let $g_n(x):\equiv x - n f(x)$. As you have noticed, we have $f(g_n(x))\equiv f(x)$, $\forall n\in\mathbb N$.

Lemma. The function $g_n:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is injective.

Proof. Let $a, b\in\mathbb R$ be such that $g_n(a) = g_n(b)$. Then

$f(g_n(a)) = f(g_n(b))\implies f(a) = f(b)$,
$a - \underline{nf(a)} = b - \underline{n f(b)}\implies a = b$,

as we wanted. $\square$
Because $g_n$ is continuous and injective, it must be monotonic. Let $(n_k)_k$ be a strictly increasing sequence of indices such that $(g_{n_k})_k$ are all monotonically increasing or all monotonically decreasing. We have
$$\begin{aligned}
x>y
\implies&& g_{n_k}(x) &\gtreqless g_{n_k}(y)\\
\implies&& x-n_k f(x) &\gtreqless y-n_k f(y)\\
\implies&& \frac{x-y}{n_k} &\gtreqless f(x)-f(y)
\end{aligned}$$
The implication holds for all $k$. By making $k\to\infty$ we get $x>y\implies f(x)\lesseqgtr f(y)$, i.e., $f$ is monotonic as well.
Now, let $x\in\mathbb R$.

If $f(x)>0$, then $f(x) = f(x-n f(x))~\forall n\in\mathbb N$ implies $\displaystyle f(-\infty) := \lim_{u\to-\infty} f(u)$ is finite and $f(x) = f(-\infty)$.
If $f(x)<0$, then $f(x) = f(x-n f(x))~\forall n\in\mathbb N$ implies $\displaystyle f(+\infty) := \lim_{u\to+\infty} f(u)$ is finite and $f(x) = f(+\infty)$.

This means the only values $f$ can assume are $0$, $f(-\infty)$ and $f(+\infty)$. Because $f$ is continuous and assumes a finite amount of values, it must be constant, as we wanted. $\square$

@Milten is that so? I don't see how to immediately get the equality $f(x+f(x)) = f(x)$ from the original statement.

This is the first time I'm seeing an answer on a question not on the hot network list that has got 7 upvotes in 2 hours of being posted!

@AlmaArjuna I'm sorry, you're right, I made a mistake in my mental calculation. (Somehow that's counterintuitive to me...)
